# Firefox redireciona para url wyciwyg://

Tags: cache, firefox

Após uma chamada Ajax, retorno o html como string e gero uma nova página com `document.write()`.

Porém ao navegar nessa página, ao usar o back ou forward do navegador, as urls das páginas começam a vir com *wyciwyg* (Ex.: `wyciwyg://4/http://localhost/`), o Firefox acaba direcionando para uma página armazenada do wyciwyg (**what you cache is what you get**). O problema, é que ele está deixando isso na url, usando o protocolo `wyciwyg` e comprometendo a url.

**Trata-se de um bug no firefox em páginas geradas com `document.write()`.**

Comment: Apaga o cache e os cookies https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/939802

Comment: Aperte `Alt` do teclado, vá até `File` e veja se está habilitado a opção `Work Offline` (se estiver em português `Arquivo` ou `Ficheiro`), verifica se o seu Firefox está atualizado, porque também pode ser um Bug, recordome que este problema ocorria no Firefox 3.5, mas já estamos no Firefox 50.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente é um bug antigo: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=387333. Só que meu firefox é a última versão (50.0.2). Não estava no modo offline, ai eu coloquei pra ver, achei curioso que no modo offline não apareceu. Tentei na versão 45 tbm, mas a msm coisa.

Comment: @YagoML poderia fornecer um exemplo bem simples de como isto ocorre com `document.write`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu simplismente retorno o html para a requisição ajax como string, após isso carrego a página usando o `write()`. A página carrega normalmente, porém quando gera histórico/cache nessa página usando o back/voltar, ao gerar de novo essa página, ela vem com o `wyciwyg://` na url. Coloquei o código de exemplo na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não consegui reproduzir o ocorrido com o seu código, estou usando Firefox 50 também, o `document.write` apenas apaga o conteúdo da página e reescreve, por exemplo:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.open();
    document.write("<strong>Resposta:<\/strong> " + (new Date()));
    document.close();
}, 1500);
```

```html
<h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
```

Todavia se é o que deseja pode trocar por `document.body.innerHTML` que talvez irá corrigir:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<strong>Resposta:<\/strong> " + (new Date());
    document.close();
}, 1500);
```

```html
<h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
```

Comment: Mudei aqui, em vez de retornar a página toda, retornei so uma parte e usei o html do jquery msm. Assim ele utiliza a mesma página e não gera cache wygiwyc, que armazena páginas escritas com write(). É um bug do firefox que persiste. Vlw ae.